# Why netbeans is trying to connect to a debug proxy?

Tags: linux, netbeans-7, xdebug

I'm trying to setup netbeans 7.3 with xdebug 2.2.1 on a Debian wheezy. I'm trying to make it work on a localhost-basis, it is, only one xdebug user connecting from the same machine (the most common configuration). After some hours I have this:

- **Xdebug is working**: I execute the `debugclient` included with the Xdebug sources and it works (i.e. when I type in the Chrome address bar `http://localhost/file.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug` the `debugclient` receives a XML response and I can interact with it sending the appropiate commands.
- **Other debug clients can connect**: I have checked that it works with Sublime Text 2 (but ST2 is not an option to substitute netbeans by the moment).
- **Netbeans is blocking when using the debugger**: If I press F6 (*Run the project*) the projet main page is launched on Chrome, but if I press CTRL+F5 (*Debug project*) a "*Waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)*" message appears and the project main page is not launched in Chrome **until** I press on *Finish debug session*. Then the page is launched but without debugging support, obviously.
- **Netbeans seems to be trying to connect to a debug proxy**: I have captured the port 9000 packets and when the other debuggers (`debugclient` and `ST2 plugin`) send XML formatted requests, `netbeans` receives a weird `proxyinit -p 9000 -k netbeans-xdebug -m 0` string. [Proxyinit](http://xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php#just-in-time-debugging-and-debugger-proxies) seems to be an informative request in order to setup multiuser system (but I only need a user).

This is the capture when using `debugclient`

[image]

and that's the same when using `netbeans`

[image]

I'm a bit confused because it is supposed that the XML message is sent by xdebug agnostically, it is, without any information about who is waiting to receive this message...

So the question is: why netbeans or xdebug (I don't know who) is trying to connect to a debug proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Netbeans is configuring the projects by default as a remote project. To disable this, you have to go to *project properties* / *Run configuration* / *Advanced* and here you have to remove *Debugger Proxy: Host* and *Port*. Click Ok and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks!  I was in the same situation, after several days of trials and errors (and many answers read on the web), this post and its answer led me to look in the right direction... I hadn't realized that debugger port (9000) and debugger proxy port (9001, eventually, not needed) referred to different services.  In most cases you'll be using only the first, so I disabled the Debugger Proxy and everything worked fine.